# ¿Como hago un fetch de todos estos datos de la pokeapi?

Tags: api, react-native

Tengo un problema y es que no se como hacer para que me muestre todas las evoluciones de este JSON
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/1/
Puedo acceder a la data con lo que hice a continuación:

```
    useEffect(() => {
const obtenerEvoluciones = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/1/`);
        console.log(res.data.chain);
};
obtenerEvoluciones()
}, [])
```

Si ingreso `console.log(res.data.chain.species.name)` me trae de resultado a Bulbasaur.
Si ingreso `console.log(res.data.chain.evolves_to[0].species.name);` me trae a ivysaur.
Ahora no se como ingresar para que tambien me traiga a Venasaur.

Lo que yo quiero es que traiga todos los evolves_to con todos los nombres de los pokemon a evolucionar mas sus evolution_details.
¿Como puedo hacer esto?
(Si no me entendieron me avisan, soy un desastre explicandome :) )

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a Venasaur, debes ir por aquí:

```
console.log(res.data.chain.evolves_to[0].evolves_to[0].species.name)
```

Comment: Pero mi codigo esta bien hecho?
Por que no se como hacer que autimaticamente recorra todos los Evolves debido a que puede haber mas de 3 pokemons

Comment: En realidad lo unico que hace es agregar evolves_to[0] cada evolución, podrías hacer un loop, con un for por ejemplo, que en cada iteración te agregue un evolves_to[0]..

Comment: Okay, vere si lo puedo hacer con el .map